# BotoCore/Boto3 Stubber Operation Not Found for generate_presigned_post

Tags: python, django, mocking, boto3, botocore

I'm trying to use the `botocore.stub.Stubber` to mock my `boto3.client`, and I am getting a `botocore.model.OperationNotFoundError` when trying to add the mocked `generate_presigned_post` response:

```
class S3FileTestCase(TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        cls.s3 = botocore.session.get_session().create_client('s3')
        cls.region_name = 'eu-west-2'

    @staticmethod
    def _mock__get_s3(region_name):
        client = boto3.client('s3', config=boto3.session.Config(signature_version='s3v4'), region_name=region_name)
        stubber = Stubber(client)

        stubber.add_response('generate_presigned_post', {'test':1}, {'bucket_name': 'test_bucket', 'region_name': region_name, 'object_name': 'test.csv'})
        return stubber

    @patch('uploader.models.s3_file.S3File._get_s3', new=_mock__get_s3)
    def test_create_presigned_post(self):
        response = S3File.create_presigned_post('stuart-special-testing-bucket', self.region_name, 'test.csv')
        print(response)
```

When I run `test_create_presigned_post` I get the `OperationNotFoundError` in the `add_reponse`. Does anyone have any idea why this might be?

Note: `S3File.create_presigned_post` is taken directly from the [docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-presigned-urls.html#generating-a-presigned-url-to-upload-a-file) with the only change being that the client is moved into a function so it can be mocked (and adding a region parameter).

Comment: Seeing this now, same command - did you resolve this?

Comment: I'm afraid not, we actually moved away from this approach as the security team decided they didn't want to expose any information about our buckets.

Comment: Great to know, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

`generate_presigned_post()` and `generate_presigned_url()` do not make API calls to S3, and therefore do not need the Stubber.

https://github.com/boto/botocore/blob/b3b5559a641c1caecaec2739564f043b61947d51/botocore/signers.py#L607

Example:

```py
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client("s3")


def get_upload_url() -> dict:
    return s3.generate_presigned_post(
        Bucket="test-bucket",
        Key="test-file.txt",
    )


def test_get_upload_url():
    response: dict = get_upload_url()
    assert "url" in response
    assert "fields" in response
```